# How to dismiss UIPopoverController and select a table cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipopovercontroller, uitapgesturerecognizer

I display a popover when a table view cell is selected. However, I would like to immediately display new contents in the popover if the user selects another table cell (instead of waiting for the popover to dismiss, then the user taps a second time to display new content).

I tried adding a UITapGestureRecognizer to the view so that I could detect table taps or taps outside of the view.  However, the tap gesture does not get called since the popover is still displayed.

I know of the UIPopoverControllerDelegate methods:
– popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:
– popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:

But returning either YES or NO from popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover does not allow the tap gesture to be called.

Any know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *passthroughViews
```

> An array of views that the user can interact with while the popover is visible.

This way your popover won't be dismissed when you tap outside the popover.

Comment: Fantastic! Works great! I added the table view as [aPopover setPassthroughViews:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[self table]]];